# How did I get a second Organizer badge on SO?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I'm sure this will be considered a minor bug (if it *is* a bug at all), but I was awarded a second Organizer badge today on Stack Overflow.  I was under the impression that this was a "one time only" badge.  Have I made so many tag edits that my counter overflowed and wrapped back around to 1?

Comment: Did you just mention an overflow? How ironic...

Comment: lol - ♦ ftw! here to organize you 'orrible lot!

Comment: That's a special "Thank you!" for all your diamond work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this a while back, it was probably due to a concurrency bug with our badge granting algorithm, we have a script that can sweep this if it happens again

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're not alone, scanning thru the people `Organizer` was [recently award to](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5), I noticed [Marc Gravel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354), [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4) and [Jarrod Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3), all of whom now have `Organizer x 2` as well.

Comment: Interesting.  Jeff Atwood and the Community user also have a pair.  Seems an awful lot like it correlates to ♦ status.