# About community user on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, community-user

What does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user do? What is its role? I read the description in which it's specified that:

> Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

What's the use of this?

**EDIT**

How this process got Editor and Organizer badge?

How he got two orgnizer badge?

Comment: Badges are awarded automatically. The Community user earned the Editor badge because it inserts the text "Possible duplicate of bla bla bla" whenever a question gets closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you flag a post as offensive/spam, it generates a downvote on that post, but it isn't owned by you (it is owned by the community user), so you don't get the -1 rep hit associated with it

Comment: ok.. thanks for this explaination. Please check edit part.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to `Editor` and `Organizer` badges, it's the Community user who automatically edits questions closed as duplicate to include a bar with links to duplicate topics in top of the question.

I'm however more interested how it got **two** Organizer badges.

Comment: thats a point dude...

Comment: I still don't know why, but all ♦ moderators got a second Organizer badge.  See: [How did I get a second Organizer badge on SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30726/how-did-i-get-a-second-organizer-badge-on-so)